# classList.toggle does not behave how it should be

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Started a project to build a website, so far was going good until this problem.

**The problem:** " I'm tried to make a dropdown menu to show options for a post(delete and edit). I made the dropdown menu and it works perfectly on my laptop(Mac-book pro, testing on google chrome), my partner on this project works on a windows desktop computer. I sent him the files for him to test, and it does not work, it does not toggle the "active" on the drop down element, we tried on his computer, chrome, fire-fox, even on his cellphone (safari and chrome) and it does not work. The click works, we tested it."

I will let you know what we did for knowing what was wrong if we could find out a solution.

**Tests:**

1. Click works, we made an alert when it was clicked so we know that it entered to the function we made
2. We did the console.log of the element after the toggle function. In this case something "weird" happened, the output was the element with the "active" on the class but the element in the dev-tool does not change.

We made it with vanilla `JS`, I could have used `jQuery`, normally I like to test things with `JavaScript` for then doing the jump to `jQuery`, but as this problem came no time for it.

Other questions you might have, is that there are going to be multiple posts, so this is the way I found to solve my problem to know in which post does the user click to make the correct dropdown.

If someone can help me to solve this I would appreciate, normally I tried to find the solutions by myself but in this case was not possible, I think it goes out of my hands and my knowledge and I find it odd that works on one computer only.

**Thank you!.**

I will show you the part of the code in case is needed.

**HTML:**

```
        <div onclick="settings(event)"class="settings" id="1508795">
            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="settingsdropdown" id="post1508795">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="editPosting.php?id=1508795">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="deletePost.php?id=1508795">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

````
function settings(e){
    var postid=e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
    var settingslist = document.getElementById('post' + postid);
    settingslist.classList.toggle("active");
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I would change the html from:

```
    <div onclick="settings(event)"class="settings" id="1508795">
```

to (note the `this`):

```
    <div onclick="settings(this)"class="settings" id="1508795">
```

Then adjust the function to be:

```
    function settings(e){
        var settingslist = document.getElementById('post' + e.id);
        settingslist.classList.toggle("active");
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we are going to test that, and let you know the outcome.